# Unable to get foreach working with canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

My setup is NodeJS connected to MongoDB using EJS.

I have a bench/lab mapping app I'm making and I was using the Lodash foreach function to populate the benches based on database objects. Currently I have this working to dynamically build an SVG image of the map, I want to start using the canvas element instead, but can't get it to work.

Here's the working SVG version:

```
<svg version="1.1"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
 x="0px" 
 y="0px"
 viewBox="0 0 520 1820" 
 enable-background="new 0 0 520 1820" 
 xml:space="preserve">
 <g id="Background">
<rect fill="#D1D3D4" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="520" height="1820"/>
</g>
    <!--Run forEach for each bench entry in DB-->
    <% _.each(labs, function(lab) { %>

    <!--Set bFill variable to null-->
        <% bFill = null; %>

    <!--Check if the bench is set to active. If true, it sets bFill to green, if not it sets to grey-->
        <% if (lab.active == true) { this.bFill='#008000'; this.LabActive+1; }else{ this.bFill='#C0C0C0' ; } %>

                <!--Fill in RECT info from DB fields-->
                <g id="<%= lab.number %>">
                    <title>- Lab bench Info - 
                    Bench: <%= lab.number %>
                    User: <%= lab.currentUser %>
                    </title>
                    <rect 
                          class="bench" 
                          id="<%= lab.number%>" 
                          x="<%= lab.x %>" 
                          y="<%= lab.y %>" 
                          fill="<%= this.bFill %>" 
                          stroke="#000000" 
                          stroke-width="0.25" 
                          stroke-miterlimit="10" 
                          width="<%= lab.w %>" 
                          height="<%= lab.h %>"  
                          />
                </g>        
                <% }) %>

</svg>
```

Here is the not working Canvas version:

```
<!--Begin Canvas-->
<canvas id="labCanvas" width="520" height="1820" style="border:5px solid #000000"></canvas>
    <script>
        var c = document.getElementById("labCanvas");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

        //      Run forEach for each bench entry in DB
    _.each(labs, function(lab) {

        //      Fill in RECT info from DB fields            

    ctx.rect(lab.x, lab.y, lab.w, lab.h);
    ctx.stroke();


                })
</script>
```

Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

Comment: "Run forEach for each bench entry in DB" should be in a comment, and where are `_` and `labs` defined?

Comment: What exactly happens in the "not working" version; nothing? Crash? An error message in F12 Developer Tools would be immensely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of poking I was able to figure out the issue. I'm putting the answer here in case someone runs across a similar issue.

Since I'm using SailsJS with EJS, the pages are being rendered on the server-side and sent to the client. This was fine when I was building the SVG version since I was making it using EJS calls, but with the new Canvas version I was using the script tags and the page was being rendered on the clients-side. So the object array my server-side controller defined (labs), was unavailable to the client. This was solved by doing a JSON.stringify to put the server (labs) array into a client-side array. Mind you, this method is dirty and insecure, but in my case the data it's grabbing is not confidential in nature.

Here is the working version of this code:

```
<!--Begin Canvas-->
<canvas id="labCanvas" width="520" height="1820" style="border:5px solid #000000"></canvas>
    <script>
        var labs = <%- JSON.stringify(labs) %>

        var c = document.getElementById("labCanvas");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

        //      Run forEach for each bench entry in DB
    labs.forEach(function(lab) {

        //      Fill in RECT info from DB fields            

    ctx.rect(lab.x, lab.y, lab.w, lab.h);
    ctx.stroke();


                });
</script>
```